# How do I stop Ember components from inheriting the class of a container component?

Tags: ember.js

So I have components with this code:

```
{{#summary-panel class="config-summary"}}
{{config-summary-body class="summary-body"
  config=model.config
  generateConfig="generateConfig"}}
{{device-summary-footer class="summary-footer"
  config=model.config
  generateConfig="generateConfig"}}    
{{/summary-panel}}
```

Seems like every component placed in the `{{yield}}` of `summary-panel` is given the class `config-summary` which breaks the CSS layout of the `device summary footer`. The reason why I'm giving them classes here is because it seems that Ember puts the component in a div which breaks the layout I'm trying to do.

We have several config-panel-xyz components that are nearly exactly the same except for a couple changes here and there. So I figured I'd break them into separate components so they are more reusable.

I don't see why Ember would give every other component inside this the same clas as it just doesn't make sense. How do I make it stop doing this?

I also on a side-note don't like that I have to give the component a class when it will/should always have that class anyway. That seems kind of ugly to me, but I don't know how else to do it because it always gives the component a div that is defined in the actual `{{component-name}}`.

Comment: Ember component won't add class to items in yield itself. It must be something else caused this.

Comment: as @JennieJi mentioned, Ember does not do that by itself. Either summary-panel is passing the classes to the children components somehow (via jquery maybe) or the children components themselves already declares that class name.

Comment: I'm not doing either @alptugd and it does do it. honestly tired of all this, it's not an isolated incident where everything that I am told should work doesn't work and everything I am told is not happening or shouldn't happen does happen.

If I remove the class name from the parent component the children don't have it anymore.but then the whole layout is borked because the parent needs it.

I decided to ditch this whole idea and just make one component like the others. We'll just have to copy/paste code.

Comment: @AlexanderRose I really do want to help you; please check out the answer I have posted. Unfortunately what you claim is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already commented to the question; what you claim is not the behavior of Ember.js. There must be something happening with the components you have designed.

Please check the [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/74e251c5cabeed9e5391d9a70755219d?openFiles=templates.components.summary-panel.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.device-summary-footer.hbs) I have prepared for you. As you can see, I have created the components with the same names as you and the classes assigned are as expected. You can check them out from your browser's debug console. `config-summary` is not being assigned as class to the other components. Please check this out and try to give more detail about your components if possible. You can even prepare a twiddle to illustrate your case; which might give us more insight about the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I don't know why it isn't working. There is one other instance where I was unable to get things to work and the person said it should work. I see in your circumstance it doesn't do it. Not sure why it's doing it in mine. I will post the components when I have some time.

Comment: this was not a big deal; I only wish we can reproduce your problem and just get  it solved. best regards